# How to convert JSON string with attribute named with parenthesis to Typescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, data-conversion

I'm working with an Angular project. From a REST web service, I received the following JSON data:

```
{
  records: [{
    Contributor(Insertion): ["rec7wILrxxqg3R5MD"],
    Country(Artist): ["E"],
    ID: 70,
    Museum: ["recFUvc63FW00oxvO"],
    Name: ["Francisco "],
    Notes: "1821-1823",
    Pictures: [{id: "attEfUG32VAK2GYSt"}],
    RecordID: "rec17E0Nisx3oRhhF",
    Title: "Saturno che divora i suoi figli",
    Year: 1823,
    id: "rec17E0Nisx3oRhhF"}
]}
```

As you can see, there is a `Contributor(Insertion)` and `Country(Artist)` field. How can I parse it and convert in a Typescript attribute? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you receive this as a string I guess, right?

Comment: This is not valid JSON.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Better to fix the backend, but lacking that, you could remove parentheses followed by colons and spaces.

Comment: Yes I receveid it from a REST service. I try to simplify the structure. To do this some clipping was done.

Comment: All keys are strings so use bracket notation ie `data["Contributor(Insertion)"]` instead of dot notation. If the name is in a variable `data[varName]`

Comment: Can you share the json-string exactly as you're receiving from back-end?

Comment: Surely those property names are double quoted and you removed the quotes for posting here?

Comment: @PatrickEvans I think the OP wants to map those keys to a specific defined-type in Typescript, therefore, this `Contributor(Insertion)` is not a valid variable/attribute name in a class for example.

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your server needs to send you a valid JSON, JSON isn't just forgiving JavaScript Object

JSON keys must be strings wrapped in two quotations

```js
export interface IMyInterface{
  "records": [{
    "key()": ["rec7wILrxxqg3R5MD"],
    "key2": ["E"],
    "key3": 70,
    "key4": ["recFUvc63FW00oxvO"],
    "key5": ["Francisco "],
    "key6": "1821-1823",
    "key7": [{"id": "attEfUG32VAK2GYSt"}],
    "key8": "rec17E0Nisx3oRhhF",
    "key9": "Saturno che divora i suoi figli",
    "key10": 1823,
    "key11": "rec17E0Nisx3oRhhF"}
]}
```

See more how to make good valid [JSON](https://www.json.org/)

Then You need to handle the function keys as class and constructor for typing.

**Pro-tip:** automate your ts interface creation : http://json2ts.com/